# Padding a navbar element affects all the navbar

Tags: html, css, hover, padding

I'm trying to make that one div in a navbar gets a top-padding when I hover it. My problem is that all my divs makes the same effect (they all go down), and I just want one of them to make this (the one I'm hovering), and I want the others to stay in the same place, with the same height, without any changes.

The current situation is this one: http://jsfiddle.net/3S8ZB/1/

This is my current CSS:

```
div {
    height: 2em;
    width: 6em;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: orange;
    display:inline-block;
}

div:hover{
    padding-top:2em;
}
```

What do you suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/3S8ZB/7/)**

`inline-block` elements are `vertically bottom alligned` by default. Add `vertical-align: top;`

css

```
div {
    height: 2em;
    width: 6em;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: orange;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: top; /* add this */
}
div:hover {
    padding-top:2em;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if understood becuse it looks like you are **very** close to that.
Padding on the hovered item and keeping the siblings vertically aligned to the top.

http://jsfiddle.net/2UvSa/

```
div {
    height: 2em;
    width: 6em;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: orange;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    transition: padding .5s ease-in;
}

div:hover{
    **padding-top:2em;**
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put `vertical-align: top;` on `div`.

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3S8ZB/6/)